# Broadcast receiver needs Wifi in each receive.Is it safe to use wifi lock and wake lock on each receive?

Tags: java, xamarin

I have create a receiver which it reads when an incoming call is coming.
When i get the call i send it through httpclient into a server.
My problem is that some times it doenst send it 
Here is my code:

```
  [BroadcastReceiver()]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" })]

public class BroadcastReceiverClass : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private string ipAdress = "";

    public void BroadcastReceiverSetIp(string ip)
    {
        ipAdress = ip;
    }
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // ensure there is information
        if (intent.Extras != null)
        {
            // get the incoming call state
            string state = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);

            // check the current state
            if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)
            {
                // read the incoming call telephone number...
                string telephone = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telephone))
                    telephone = string.Empty;

                sendTelephone(telephone,context);

            }

        }
    }
    private async void sendTelephone(string telephone, Context context)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAdress))
            {


                if (telephone.Length == 13)
                    telephone = telephone.Substring(3);

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000);
                    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://" + ipAdress + ":9090/api/SqlAction/", new StringContent("20:" + telephone, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                }

            }




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CatchException.LogFile(this.Class.SimpleName, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am register my Broadcast receiver inside from an activity.

```
  var receiver = new BroadcastReceiverClass();
                    receiver.BroadcastReceiverSetIp(MyIp);
                    RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
                    this.MoveTaskToBack(true);
```

Is it safe to use wake lock and wifi lock each time i am getting a receive?Like example below

```
   private async void sendTelephone(string telephone, Context context)
    {
        try
        {

            var pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            var wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "MyWakeLock");
            wakeLock.Acquire();


            var wm = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            var wifiLock = wm.CreateWifiLock(WifiMode.FullHighPerf, "MyWifiLock");
            wifiLock.Acquire();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAdress))
            {
                if (telephone.Length == 13)
                    telephone = telephone.Substring(3);

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000);
                    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://" + ipAdress + ":9090/api/SqlAction/", new StringContent("20:" + telephone, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                }
            }
            if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.IsHeld)
                wakeLock.Release();

            if (wifiLock != null && wifiLock.IsHeld)
                wifiLock.Release();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CatchException.LogFile(this.Class.SimpleName, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would better display an alert to notify the user that the app will open  wifi when first received the calling , which is friendly to users .